# TSQL query returning double the rows with inner join of same table twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to return all middle/highschool courses taught by a given teacher. With an inner join of two tables, 3 rows are displayed correctly. When I do 2nd inner join with the 3rd table, it returns 6 rows instead of 3.

Without using cte, DISTINCT, how can I display 3 rows with empid, the middle classes, and the high school classes? Also, both foreign tables should do joins with the primary table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#empl') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #empl
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#middlecourses') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #middlecourses
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#highcourses') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #highcourses

create table #empl
(
    EmpId int,
    Grade int
)
insert into #empl select 1, 5   

create table #middlecourses
(
    EmpId int,
    Grade int,
    Course varchar(20)
)
insert into #middlecourses select 1, 5, 'Science'
insert into #middlecourses select 1, 5, 'Math'  
insert into #middlecourses select 1, 5, 'English'

create table #highcourses
(
    EmpId int,
    Grade int,
    Course varchar(20)
)
insert into #highcourses select 1, 5, 'Calculus'
insert into #highcourses select 1, 5, 'Physics' 
insert into #highcourses select 1, 5, 'CompSci'

select e.empid, e.grade, m.course as 'MiddleCourse'
from #empl e inner join #middlecourses m
on e.empid = m.empid 
and e.grade = m.grade

select e.empid, e.grade, m.course as 'MiddleCourse', h.course as 'HighCourse'
from #empl e inner join #middlecourses m
on e.empid = m.empid 
and e.grade = m.grade
inner join #highcourses h
on e.empid = h.empid
and e.grade = h.grade

drop table #empl
drop table #middlecourses
drop table #highcourses
```

Comment: Your second query returns 9 rows because it is joining a set of 1 (your `#empl`), onto a set of 3 (`#middlecourses`) and then a set of 3 again (`#highcourses`). What do you think the results should end up being? How should  Science be matched to Physics, for example, rather than CompSci?

Comment: The result should be 3 rows; like two separate inner joins joined into one resultset.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a more elegant solution, but this should do the trick for the scenario given:

```
select e.empid, e.grade, c.course, c.CourseType
from #empl e 
inner join 
(
SELECT *, 'MiddleCourse' AS CourseType
FROM #middlecourses m 
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'HighCourse' AS CourseType
FROM #highcourses h
) c ON c.EmpId = e.EmpId AND c.Grade = e.Grade
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because all of your `empid` and `grade` are the same.  This join is matching many times.

You're already seeing this in your first join, the rows in `#Empl` are being duplicated three times (becuase it matches all 3 records in `#MiddleCourses`).

To reduce these you need to use a more exlusive join and / or use differing data.  Try changing the `empid` and `grade` and you'll hopefully see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by  using a more exlusive join and / or use differing data? I can't filter by #Empl.EmpId or #Empl.Grade because I need to return everything in #Empl.

Comment: Well the join is matching so many times because your conditions are true (because `emp` and `grade` are all the same value`).  To be more exclusive you'd need more information so you could reduce by classroom etc.  I would change the numbers so you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to match `middlecourses` with `highcourses` depending on alphabetical `course` ordering:

```
select e.empid, e.grade, m.course as 'MiddleCourse', h.course as 'HighCourse'
from #empl e 
cross apply (
   SELECT course, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by course) as rn
   FROM #middlecourses m
   WHERE e.empid = m.empid AND e.grade = m.grade ) m
cross apply (
   SELECT course, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by course) as rn
   FROM #highcourses h
   WHERE e.empid = h.empid AND e.grade = h.grade ) h
where m.rn = h.rn
```

**Output:**

```
empid   grade   MiddleCourse    HighCourse
-------------------------------------------
1       5       English         Calculus
1       5       Math            CompSci
1       5       Science         Physics
```

The above will only work in case there is an equal number of `middlecourses` and `highcourses`.

In case there is a mismatch between the number of  `middlecourses` and `highcourses` you can use a bit more complicated variation of the above query:

```
SELECT e.EmpId, e.Grade, t.MiddleCourse, t.HighCourse
FROM #empl e
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT COALESCE(m.empid, h.empid) AS empid, 
          COALESCE(m.grade, h.grade) AS grade,
          m.Course AS 'MiddleCourse', h.Course as 'HighCourse'
   FROM (SELECT empid, grade, course, 
                ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by empid, grade 
                                   order by course) as rn
         FROM #middlecourses) m
   FULL JOIN (SELECT empid, grade, course, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by empid, grade 
                                        order by course) as rn
              FROM #highcourses) h 
   ON m.EmpId = h.EmpId AND m.Grade = h.Grade AND m.rn = h.rn ) t
ON e.EmpId = t.empid AND e.Grade = t.grade
```

With one more record in `highcourses`:

```
insert into #highcourses select 1, 5, 'Algebra'
```

**output is:**

```
EmpId   Grade   MiddleCourse    HighCourse
-------------------------------------------
1       5       English         Algebra
1       5       Math            Calculus
1       5       Science         CompSci
1       5       NULL            Physics
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, edmondson is correct.
What you could do is a simple pivot with a ROW_NUMBER() to make the rows unique.

```
select
    *
from
(
    select e.empid, e.grade, 'MiddleCourses' as [Type] , m.course, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.EmpId) ClassNo
    from #empl e inner join #middlecourses m
    on e.empid = m.empid 
    and e.grade = m.grade
    union all
    select e.empid, e.grade, 'HighCourses' as [Type] ,m.course, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.EmpId) ClassNo
    from #empl e inner join #highcourses m
    on e.empid = m.empid 
    and e.grade = m.grade
) SourceTable
pivot
(
    MIN(Course)
    FOR [Type] IN (MiddleCourses,HighCourses)
) pivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

> First of all you need to understand how inner join works. Inner join
>   will get you the record which are present in both the tables which you
>   are joining.

coming to your question, when you execute the following query

```
select e.empid, e.grade, m.course as 'MiddleCourse'
from #empl e inner join #middlecourses m
on e.empid = m.empid 
and e.grade = m.grade
```

you will get this record.

```
empid   grade   MiddleCourse
1   5   Science
1   5   Math
1   5   English
```

so you get 3 records which is expected, because there are 3 records in #middlecourse table with empid = 1. So it inner join is work like this. It will pick one empid at a time from #empl table and will try to find the matching rows for this empiid in the second table i.e #middlecourses

So you have 3 records from above query. Now when you will add the second inner join then it will try to get empid from above 3 record  and will match with the third table which is #highcoures. So for every empiid it will return 3 record. so total you will have **3*3 = 9** record from second query like this.

```
EmpId   Grade   EmpId   Grade   Course  EmpId   Grade   Course
1        5      1       5       Science  1      5      Calculus
1        5      1       5       Math     1      5      Calculus
1        5      1       5       English  1      5      Calculus
1        5      1       5       Science  1      5      Physics
1        5      1       5       Math     1      5      Physics
1        5      1       5       English  1      5      Physics
1        5      1       5       Science  1      5      CompSci
1        5      1       5       Math     1      5      CompSci
1        5      1       5       English  1      5      CompSci
```

One solution for this scenario would be do union on your courses table and then do the inner join with #empl table.

```
select e.EmpId, e.Grade, a.Course from #empl e
inner join (
select * 
from #middlecourses
union
select * from #highcourses) a on e.EmpId = a.EmpId
```

Comment: I understand how an inner join works and I understand why it's returning so many rows. You didn't post a suggestion. How come?